# C#. Regex to check if all params begin with "p_" in sql procedure

Tags: c#, regex

how to check if all parameters in procedure begins with "p_" using a regex?

Procedure sample:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_in_sys_blablabla`$$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_in_sys_blablabla`(
    p_cod_componente INT(11),
    cod_tipo_ocorrencia SMALLINT(4), 
    p_dat_inicio CHAR(30), 
    dat_fim CHAR(30), 
    p_cod_usu_inc CHAR(10), 
    p_datInc CHAR(40)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_excecao SMALLINT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET v_excecao = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
......
END$$
```

C# code:

```
string content = "proceddure code"; 
Regex regex = new Regex(regras[i].Regex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (regex.IsMatch(content)) Console.WriteLine(ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: I think this should be done using a grammar.

Comment: @Matthias Koch: sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view you have two options:

1. You can use regular expressions. Read your sql statement line by line. Be sure, that you're inside the declaration of a procedure! I think that is very error-prone due to the fact, that it is not necessary by syntax. The actual regular expression seems very easy `p_[a-z]+`.
2. Use a parser (i.e., [Gold parser](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/)). Possibly you'll find a grammar for SQL syntax. You can then grab any *parameter* within a procedure declaration and check whether it `StartsWith("p_")`.

Answer (score 0):

best way to check procedures is using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.
This package provide complete support to validate statements in procedure, step by step.